# Return value is a "unresolved name"

Tags: rust

I been trying to implement a restful server that returns some JSONed data from a database in a HTTP get response. I'm using [rustful](https://github.com/Ogeon/rustful) crate. So far, I'm able to retrieve the data but I couldn't figure out how to return them in the response body.

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate rustful;
extern crate rustc_serialize;
extern crate postgres;

use std::error::Error;

use rustful::{Server, Context, Response, TreeRouter, Log, Handler};
use rustful::context::ExtJsonBody;
use postgres::{Connection, SslMode};

#[derive(RustcEncodable,RustcDecodable)]
struct Coord {
    lat: f64,
    long: f64,
    expr: String
}

fn get(context: Context, response: Response) {
    let conn = Connection::connect("postgresql://postgres:password@localhost", &SslMode::None).unwrap();
    let stmt = conn.prepare("SELECT latitude,longitude,expiry FROM coord LIMIT 1").unwrap();
    let result = stmt.query(&[]).unwrap();
    for row in result {
       let coord = Coord {
            lat: row.get(0),
            long: row.get(1),
            expr: row.get(2)
        };
       println!("Latitude: {}\nLongitude: {}\nExpiry: {}", coord.lat, coord.long, coord.expr);
    }
    response.send(format!("{:?}", coord.lat))
}

struct HandlerFn(fn(Context, Response));

impl Handler for HandlerFn {
    fn handle_request(&self, context: Context, response: Response) {
        self.0(context, response);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let server = Server {
        host: 8080.into(),
        handlers: insert_routes! {
            TreeRouter::new() => {
                Get: HandlerFn(get)
            }
        },
        ..Server::default()
    }.run();

    match server {
        Ok(_server) => {},
        Err(e) => println!("Cannot start server: {}", e.description())
    }
}
```

The code currently fails with this error:

```
src/main.rs:40:35: 40:40 error: unresolved name `coord`
src/main.rs:40     response.send(format!("{:?}", coord.lat))
                                                 ^~~~~
note: in expansion of format_args!
<std macros>:2:26: 2:57 note: expansion site
<std macros>:1:1: 2:61 note: in expansion of format!
src/main.rs:40:19: 40:45 note: expansion site
error: aborting due to previous error
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read about creating a [MCVE](/help/mcve), which serves to highlight the problem to both yourself and to potential answerers. In this case, you have quite a lot of code that is ancillary to your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variables have a *lexical scope*, that is, where a variable is available is tied to the curly braces in the source code. Here's a small example:

```
fn main() {
    {
        let value = 42;
    }
    println!("{}", value);
}
```

`value` is not accessible outside of the curly braces in which it is defined.

You have the same problem in your case:

```
for row in result {
   let coord = Coord {...};
}
response.send(format!("{:?}", coord.lat))
```

Each iteration of the loop, `coord` is created and then is dropped. There is nothing that corresponds to the name `coord` outside of the loop.

It's difficult to tell you how to fix your problem. The [docs for `Response::send`](http://ogeon.github.io/docs/rustful/master/rustful/response/struct.Response.html#method.send) say (emphasis mine):

> Send data to the client and **finish** the response

Which means you can only send a single response. You are going to have to figure out how to combine all of your results and then send them back together. Probably a JSON array would fit the bill.